# Receiving blank PDF from BLOB data in my database

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, pdf, blob

I'm storing my PDF files into my SQL database using C# and using BLOB(long) as my SQL datatype.

C# code:

Convert PDF to bytes

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(bytes, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
```

Storing bytes into the database

```
string query = "INSERT INTO invoices (data, dateTime, invoiceNo, ni) VALUES (@d, @dt, @in, @ni)";
var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbCon.Connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", bytes);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dateTime);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@in", invoiceNo);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ni", ni);

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Database table structure (Using longblob):

[image]

Now, that is all done from the client application and there are multiple records, on the web side, i'm trying to pull that blob data from the database and convert it back to PDF and download it. It all works great apart from the PDF is blank even though there is an average of 170kb per PDF.

Web side:

I'm getting the blob data from the database and trying to convert it into a PDF file using this JavaScript function:

```js
    function convertInvoiceBlob(fileName, resData) {
        
        var newBlob = new Blob([resData], {type: "application/pdf"});

        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
            return;
        } 

        const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = data;
        link.download= fileName;
        link.click();
        
        setTimeout(function(){
            // For Firefox it is necessary to delay revoking the ObjectURL
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
        }, 100);
    }
```

However I'm receiving a blank PDF. I'm not quite sure which part I have mistakes at, whether its storing it into the database incorrectly or receiving the data and converting it incorrectly.

Comment: Easiest way to check is to get the output from the browser and use a diff tool to compare it byte-for-byte with the known good source PDF.

Comment: Have you tried taking that file stream that you are sending to the DB and instead immediately converting back to PDF (i.e. skipping storing it) and see if that works? That would eliminate or confirm the DB as a source of the issue.

Comment: Hi Navik, Yes, i have converted the bytes to PDF before uploading and DB and it converts it correctly